# Found this on The Ohio State University campus on a pillar relatively hidden from view. Any leads? I’m clueless

Tags: cipher, no-computers

Here is the photo of the code... I think. I don’t know what it could be, but it was duct taped to a pillar for several weeks before I was kicked off campus from COVID-19:

[image: COVID-19]

Comment: It is simple A1-Z26 code.

Comment: Better: A01-Z26.

Answer (score 2):

> It is a simple cipher where letters are replaced with their position in the alphabet (A = 1, Z = 26).

It appears to say

> LOOK THROUGH THE EYEHOLE THAT'S THE KEYHOLE THAT'S THE EYEHOLE THAT'S THE KEYHOLE